Page Builder Plugin for Nodejs
I'm looking for some suggestions for a page builder to include in our Next.js project. Here are the requirements:

Can be hosted locally
Can save data in a local database
Can export HTML and CSS

I previously used GrapesJS and even managed to create a custom plugin for a carousel. However, our client no longer prefers GrapesJS, as they find it challenging for users without development experience. Although Studio GrapesJS is good, it is still in alpha stage and, as far as I know, its repository is not yet public.
Can you suggest any other page builder plugins I can use (excluding WordPress) that meet these criteria?
Thank you in advance for your help :)
PS: I did work hard on that carousel custom plugin so I might cry idk
